# PATH/PYTHONPATH is not working

Tags: python, django, path, pythonpath

I've made a separate directory for my django modules. I've added this directory to my PATH variable. I've also created a new PYTHONPATH variable, since it wasn't there. I've added modules to settings.py. But when im trying to run manage.py syncdb for the new module it still says

```
Error: No module named my_module
```

Why, oh why?

EDIT: I didn't created the app with manage.py startapp, but manually created the files. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: Please show both the value of PYTHONPATH and the real path to my_module.

Comment: my_module is in: E:\Sites\django-projects
PYTHONPATH: E:\Python\Scripts;E:\Sites\django-projects
In the Python\Scripts I have a django-admin.py file, maybe I have to copy it to django-projects too? Or maybe its the "-" thats messing things up?

Answer (score 2):

PATH tells your shell where to find executables; it has nothing to do with Python.  PYTHONPATH is a list of directories to search for Python modules.  It should be edited to include the directory with my_module.

Comment: "PYTHONPATH is a list of directories to search of Python modules. It should include the directory with my_module." It does.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell you what the issue is with only that output, however this should solve the problem:

Inside `bar.py` or `bar/__init__.py`

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Now, in other files you can `import bar`